# awk output repeating last line even though only appears once in input

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below, which executes and produces the data lines needed in the output. However the last line in the output `No Additional CNV Detected` is repeated and I'm not sure why as it is only in the input `file1` once. I am adding the selcted fields from `file2` to `file1` but the last line repeats. Do i need and `END` or something else. Thank you :).

**file1**

```
Controls:
4 expression controls detected
13 NOCALL detected
2178 REF detected
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected
No Oncomine Drivers Detected
No Additional Clinvar Detected
No Additional Function Detected
No Additional Fusion Detected
No Additional Hotspots Detected
No Additional CNV Detected
```

**file2**

```
Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
2353    1   99.9575
```

**awk**

```
awk '{getline f1 <"file1" ;print f1,$1,$2,$3}' OFS="\t" file2 > out
```

**current out**

```
Controls:   Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
4 expression controls detected  2353    1   99.9575
13 NOCALL detected          
2178 REF detected           
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected         
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected         
No Oncomine Drivers Detected            
No Additional Clinvar Detected          
No Additional Function Detected         
No Additional Fusion Detected           
No Additional Hotspots Detected         
No Additional CNV Detected          
No Additional CNV Detected          
No Additional CNV Detected          
No Additional CNV Detected
```

**desired out**

```
Controls:   Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
4 expression controls detected  2353    1   99.9575
13 NOCALL detected          
2178 REF detected           
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected         
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected         
No Oncomine Drivers Detected            
No Additional Clinvar Detected          
No Additional Function Detected         
No Additional Fusion Detected           
No Additional Hotspots Detected         
No Additional CNV Detected
```

Comment: Your output should only have as many lines as are in file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print $0,a[FNR]}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

You could take it's output to a output file by doing `> outfile` at the last of the command.

Answer (score 3):

Using `paste`

```
paste file1 file2 > outputfile
```

Using `pr`

```
pr -mtJ file1 file2 > outputfile
```

> Test Results:

***Input files:***

```
$ cat f1
Controls:
4 expression controls detected
13 NOCALL detected
2178 REF detected
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected
No Oncomine Drivers Detected
No Additional Clinvar Detected
No Additional Function Detected
No Additional Fusion Detected
No Additional Hotspots Detected
No Additional CNV Detected

$ cat f2
Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
2353    1   99.9575
```

**Output from  `paste` command:**

```
$ paste f1 f2
Controls:   Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
4 expression controls detected  2353    1   99.9575
13 NOCALL detected  
2178 REF detected   
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected 
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected 
No Oncomine Drivers Detected    
No Additional Clinvar Detected  
No Additional Function Detected 
No Additional Fusion Detected   
No Additional Hotspots Detected 
No Additional CNV Detected
```

**Output from  `pr` command:**

```
$ pr -mtJ f1 f2
Controls:   Total_Targets     Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
4 expression controls detected  2353    1   99.9575
13 NOCALL detected  
2178 REF detected   
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P absent controls detected 
0 ASSAYS_5P_3P NoCall controls detected 
No Oncomine Drivers Detected    
No Additional Clinvar Detected  
No Additional Function Detected 
No Additional Fusion Detected   
No Additional Hotspots Detected 
No Additional CNV Detected
```